# Why (php) preg_match returning an array of 2 even if there is only one invalid character?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Why preg_match return an array of 2 values even if there is only one
invalid character?

```
function check_alpha($str)
{
    preg_match("/([^A-Za-z])/",$str,$result);
    var_dump($result); 
}
```

Sending this string `testing5this`

Returning :

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '5' (length=1)
  1 => string '5' (length=1)
```

Comment: In addition to what chiris85 mentioned you could also do `$result[1]` if you wanted a capture group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `0` index is the full match. The `1` is the first capture group.

You can see it here, https://regex101.com/r/PFqC1K/1/.

You don't need the capture group. e.g.

```
preg_match("/[^A-Za-z]/",'testing5this',$result);
var_dump($result);
```

Will bring back just the match.

https://eval.in/771077